# Refresh Datagrid automatically when its ItemsSource changed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, refresh

I'm using a datagrid in a UserControl. How can I refresh Datagrid automatically when its ItemsSource changed without using DataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Comment: how to you bind the ItemsSource to your DataGrid. MVVM with Binding or codebehind... you should give some more information,because there are several ways.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is use an observable collection.

here is an old but valid example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

Comment: Setting the ItemsSource Binding Mode to 2way makes no sense. i think you should edit your answer

Comment: @Kaizen, there is no need for this to be `TwoWay`. `ItemsSource` bindings work by reference, so when Add/Delete/Edit takes place on an editable datagrid, the chages reflect back to the source observable collection automatically (inspite of the binding mode).

Comment: Yes,I changed it to the observable collection, the problem is I have a TemplateSelector my DataGrid's DataGridTemplateColumn won't be updated, the TemplateSelector won't be called after any exist thing changed. It only update after add/delete.